# Where is data corruption during copying files likely to happen?

Tags: hard-drive, file-transfer, storage, data-transfer, file-corruption

Assuming both the source and target devices are in good working order, where is corruption most likely to happen (if it does)? For example, suppose that I'm backing up stuff from an internal HD to an external USB drive - are undetected errors likely to occur during read from the platter, inside drive caches/controllers, transfer from the drive, on CPU/Memory, in transit through USB or when physically writing to the target platter? Here I'm concerned with transfer alone, not long-term storage issues like bit rot.

Comment: Basically read/write/transfer errors. All 3 can occur. It really depends on the hardware, operating system's role, interferences caused by software those might involve in and interfere hardware/communication procedures and might affect in different stages. This detection is also depending on the communication procedures. HDD might not report all issues to the operating system - depends on the vendor standards. Unless there is a significance. It is somewhat difficult to provide a straight answer as the category is broad. Are you specifically focussing on this scenario (HDD to USB)?

Comment: I dont know where it occurs in the process, but undetected error can occur if your ram isnt perfect. when overclocking and timing ram or even using XMP profiles adjusting voltage and all, that not being perfect can cause tiny imperceptable changes in the file transferred. Using a compare routine after copying can spot that. Take windows copying doesnt full compare without using a different program (like windiff) or 3rd party copying like terracopy and fastcopy. it can be a real concern. It has also happened here when the ram began to fail after working perfect for many years.